# system("") call in AWK executing only last line

Tags: awk

I have written an awk script that takes some values from a file.txt and for each row of this file makes a call `system("...")`.
The problem is that the terminal takes only the last system call.

I need that every `system("...")` call being called for each row of my `file.txt` gets executed.

For example: `file.txt`

```
00:00:6c:19:8f:b1:d8:27 10.0.0.10 1 
00:00:6c:19:8f:b1:d8:27 10.0.0.11 1 
00:00:6c:19:8f:b1:d8:28 10.0.0.12 3
00:00:6c:19:8f:b1:d8:28 10.0.0.11 2
```

For example file.awk:

```
BEGIN {

}
{
switch_mac=$1
ip_dst=$2
output_port=$3

system("curl" " -d" " '{" "\"switch\""":" "\""switch_mac"\"""," "\"cookie\""":""\"1\"""," "\"priority\""":""\"2\"""," "\"eth_type\""":""\"0x0800\"""," "\"ipv4_dst\""":""\""ip_dst"\"""," "\"active\""":""\"true\"""," "\"actions\""":""\"output="output_port"\"""}'" " http://10.0.0.11:8080/wm/staticflowpusher/json")

//here i need to have the execution of the system call
}
```

Comment: Why do you want this to be in `awk`?

Comment: What is the actual `curl` command you want to run - can you give an example without all the awful quotes needed because of `awk`?

Comment: In AWK, placing two strings next to each other is string concatenation.  So all those quotes aren't needed; they do nothing but clutter up the code.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling an external process once per line anyway so any speedup you might expect to see from using awk to read the file isn't worth worrying about:

```
while read -r switch_mac ip_dst output_port; do
    # your curl command with "$switch_mac", "$ip_dst" and "$output_port" (include the quotes!)
done < file.txt
```

You can capture the response using `output=$(curl ...)` if you so desire, or even pipe the output of the loop to awk if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it all simply enough in parallel with **GNU Parallel** along these lines:

```
parallel --colsep ' ' -a file.txt echo curl -d '{"switch": "{1}", "cookie":"1", "priority":"2", "ip4_dst":"{2}", "active":"true", "actions":"output={3}"}' http://192.168.0.1:8080/wm/staticflowpusher/json
```

**Output**

```
curl -d {switch: 00:00:6c:19:8f:b1:d8:27, cookie:1, priority:2, ip4_dst:10.0.0.10, active:true, actions:output=1} http://192.168.0.1:8080/wm/staticflowpusher/json
curl -d {switch: 00:00:6c:19:8f:b1:d8:27, cookie:1, priority:2, ip4_dst:10.0.0.11, active:true, actions:output=1} http://192.168.0.1:8080/wm/staticflowpusher/json
curl -d {switch: 00:00:6c:19:8f:b1:d8:28, cookie:1, priority:2, ip4_dst:10.0.0.12, active:true, actions:output=3} http://192.168.0.1:8080/wm/staticflowpusher/json
curl -d {switch: 00:00:6c:19:8f:b1:d8:28, cookie:1, priority:2, ip4_dst:10.0.0.11, active:true, actions:output=2} http://192.168.0.1:8080/wm/staticflowpusher/json
```

Remove the word `echo` from the command if the output looks correct, then it will actually run the commands rather than echo them. Note that the `echo` is currently hiding some double quotes. Note also that I changed the final IP address so it works on my network here.